# Multiple filtering by SKUS for products in categories

Tags: magento2.4.2

In the administrative panel, in the Categories section, there is a Products in Categories tab. In this tab, you can filter products by sku. I need to be able to specify multiple skus separated by commas. Is it possible to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to rewrite tab `Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product` class and use the `_prepareColumns()` method.

First, create preference in **etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product"
                type="Anna\CategoryProductMultipleSkus\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product"/>

</config>
```

In the `_prepareColumns()` method, retrieve the data from the 'sku' column and set additional information. We need to add the property `filter_condition_callback` and set it as an array containing the class object and the method name to handle filtering.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Anna\CategoryProductMultipleSkus\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended;

class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product
{
    protected function _prepareColumns(): Extended
    {
        $result = parent::_prepareColumns();
        $childSkuBlock = $result->getColumnSet()->getChildBlock('sku');
        $skuColumnData = $childSkuBlock->getData();

        $skuColumnData['filter_condition_callback'] = [$this, 'filterProductSkuList'];
        $childSkuBlock->setData($skuColumnData);

        return $result;
    }

    public function filterProductSkuList($collection, $column): self
    {
        $filter = $column->getFilter();
        $value = $filter->getValue();

        if (!($value)) {
            return $this;
        }

        $skus = explode(",", str_replace("%", "", $value));
        $attrs = [];

        foreach ($skus as $sku) {
            $attrs[] = ['attribute' => 'sku', 'like' => '%' . trim($sku) . '%'];
        }

        $collection->addFieldToFilter($attrs);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

After the changes, the SQL search for 'WSH12,WSH11' would appear as follows:

```
 SELECT `e`.*, `at_position`.`position` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `at_position` ON 
 (at_position.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND (category_id=2) WHERE (`e`.`entity_id` IN(47, .... , 2043)) AND ((`e`.`sku` LIKE '%WSH12%') OR (`e`.`sku` LIKE '%WSH11%'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            <?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace vendor\module\Block\Adminhtml\;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended;

class classname extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product
{
    protected function _prepareColumns(): Extended
    {
        $result = parent::_prepareColumns();
        $childSkuBlock = $result->getColumnSet()->getChildBlock('sku');
        $skuColumnData = $childSkuBlock->getData();

        $skuColumnData['filter_condition_callback'] = [$this, 'filterProductSkuList'];
        $childSkuBlock->setData($skuColumnData);

        return $result;
    }

    public function filterProductSkuList($collection, $column): self
    {
        $filter = $column->getFilter();
        $value = $filter->getValue();

        if (!($value)) {
            return $this;
        }

        $skus = explode(",", str_replace("%", "", $value));
        $attrs = [];

        foreach ($skus as $sku) {
            $attrs[] = ['attribute' => 'sku', 'like' => '%' . trim($sku) . '%'];
        }

        $collection->addFieldToFilter($attrs);

        return $this;
    }}
```